# Output Tensor Wrong Shape When Parsing TFRecord

Tags: python, parsing, tensorflow

When I attempt to parse a TFRecord file I am getting the following error:

```
(<tf.Tensor 'ParseSingleExample/Squeeze_tokens:0' shape=() dtype=int64>, <tf.Tensor 'ParseSingleExample/Squeeze_labels:0' shape=() dtype=int64>)
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:940] Invalid argument: Name: <unknown>, Key: tokens, Index: 0.  Number of int64 values != expected.  values size: 5 but output shape: []
```

As far as I can tell the line error implies that the output tensor is the wrong shape. I have been following the information [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/reading_data/) for the most part. Under the heading **Standard TensorFlow format** it lists two github links that both encode and parse the mnist dataset. In the file that performs the parsing there is no reference to setting the output tensors shape as far as I can tell. I'm not sure how to correct this and I have tried everything I can think of. I have included my code below.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tempfile
import os

def make_example(sequence, label):
    #converts a sequence and its labels into a SequenceExample

    # The object we return
    ex = tf.train.Example()
    # Feature lists for the two sequential features of our example
    fl_tokens = ex.features.feature["tokens"]
    fl_labels = ex.features.feature["labels"]
    for token in sequence:
        fl_tokens.int64_list.value.append(token)

    fl_labels.int64_list.value.append(label)

    return ex

def parse_example(filename_queue):
    #reads a TFRecord into its constituent parts

    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
    _, example = reader.read(filename_queue)

    # Parse the example
    sequence_parsed = tf.parse_single_example(
        serialized=example,
        features={
            "tokens": tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.int64),
            "labels": tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.int64)
        }
    )

    return sequence_parsed["tokens"], sequence_parsed["labels"]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sequence = [1,2,3,4,5]
    label = 1
    #################################
    # Write all examples into a TFRecords file
    #################################
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(dir=".") as fp:
        writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(fp.name)

        ex = make_example(sequence, label)
        writer.write(ex.SerializeToString())
        writer.close()

        #################################
        # Read contents of TFRecord file
        #################################

        filename = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), fp.name)
        filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([filename])

        with tf.Session() as sess:
            coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
            tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
            out_sequence, out_label = parse_example(filename_queue)


            # Print the contents of a single entry:
            v1,v2 = sess.run([out_sequence, out_label])
            print(v1,v2)
```

--

EDIT: So I figured out that I can get rid of the error and have things work by changing the line

```
"tokens": tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.int64)
```

to

```
"tokens": tf.FixedLenFeature([5], dtype=tf.int64)
```

This forces the shape of the output tensor. I'm still unclear why I need to specify this for the case I have presented while the example in the tensorflow directions does not. If someone could clarify I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: The parsing of `FixedLenFeature` enforces that the feature has the correct number of elements; it will issue an error if there is a mismatch with the data.

Comment: Ok, so why am I allowed to use and empty shape ([ ]) in some cases but not in others?

Comment: Can you show the example where the empty shape is allowed? (The empty shape is a legal shape; it means "scalar".)